# Fill Polygon Area Html5 Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

This is HTML code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="draw" onclick="setdraw()" />
<input type="button" value="fill" onclick="setfill()" />
<div id="drawarea">
</div>
```

This is Javascript Code

```
var flag = false;
var pen_arr = [];
var drawble = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
});

function setfill(){
    drawble = false;
}

function setdraw(){
    drawble = true;
}

function init(){
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'drawarea',
        width: 500,
        height: 800
    });

    background = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0, 
        y: 0, 
        width: stage.getWidth(),
        height: stage.getHeight()
    });

    layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    layer.add(background);

    stage.add(layer);

    stage.on("mousedown", mouseDown );
    stage.on("mousemove", mouseMove );
    stage.on("mouseup",   mouseUp );
}

function mouseDown(){

  if (drawble === true){   
    flag = true;
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var tmp_pen = new Kinetic.Line({
        points:[mousePos.x, mousePos.y, mousePos.x + 1, mousePos.y + 1 ],
        stroke: "blue",  
        strokeWidth: 3
    });
    layer.add(tmp_pen );    
    pen_arr.push(tmp_pen );
    layer.drawScene();   
  }else{
     flag = false;

    // in here i have to carry fill function
    // when i click in stage, i have to set the fill color in closed area after drawing pen
  }

}

function mouseMove(){
    if(flag === true ) {
        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
        var tmp_pen = pen_arr[pen_arr.length - 1];
        var points = tmp_pen.getPoints();
        points.push({x:mousePos.x,y:mousePos.y});
        tmp_pen.setPoints(points);
        layer.drawScene(); 
    }
}

function mouseUp(){
    flag = false;    
}
```

Check this result, please.

In here you can check some drawing sample 
There are two button "fill" and "draw"
You can draw pen by clicking "draw" button
We have to set the fill color by clicking "fill" button
After clicking "fill" button, we can click any point on the stage.
At that time, we have to set the fill color the area closed

So My question is "I have to set the fill color in the area closed"

Comment: Please post the relevant code on here.  SO doesn't allow links to jsfiddle without code; I'm surprised that jsbin passes the filter.  Also, please tell us what problem you're having with your current solution attempt.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to give you code.
Check this out:

```
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/
```

Comment: thanks, i will wait a good news. you can check http://jsbin.com/omuwor/3/edit

Comment: I found this, you can do it with draws: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/